# оформление цитат по типу прямой речи без глаголов речи, чувств

Tags: цитата, бессоюзное

В лингвистических, литературоведческих трудах с обильным иллюстративным материалом неоднократно встречала такой способ оформления цитаты, когда она размещается после двоеточия в кавычках, при этом предшествующая ей часть предложения не содержит глаголов речи, чувств и пр., например:

Понятие блудного сына распространяется на весь род людской, предавший Отца небесного ради благ телесных, временных, иллюзорных: "За все по совокупности спаси Господи народ мой..."

Так как мне и самой предстоит публикация монографии, хотелось бы узнать, является ли такой способ приведения чужого текста корректным и чем он регламентируется.

Comment: Оно должно быть связано по смыслу, не вижу здесь связи.

Comment: Оно связано логически. Вторая часть выступает аргументом к первой. Еще пример, уже из словаря: Варьирование образа автора находит отражение в варьировании языковой формы: "С радостным светлым чувством я обращаюсь к вам со словами мира и любви о Христе..."

Comment: Аргументом к чему именно? К какому тезису? Там не аргумент, а просьба. Ещё в этом примере "Господи" — обращение, то есть нужны запятые. Загуглите, запятые ставятся, если молитва. Во втором примере тоже не всё понятно. Короче, нужны понятные примеры, тогда, думаю, будут ответы.

Comment: Хорошо, еще примеры.
1) В финале "Преступления и наказания" Раскольников оказывается на берегу реки: "С высокого берега открывалась широкая окрестность". 2) Влечет к православию отнюдь не истина, а поэзия: "Поэзия религиозных впечатлений способствует сохранению в сердце любви к религии..."

Comment: Во втором примере нормально. Двоеточие ставится, когда рассказываем о том, о чём сказано в первой части (об этой поэзии). В первом утверждение, а потом текст в подтверждение, но в цитате о Раскольникове не сказано, то есть она не подтверждает.

Comment: В фрагменте с Раскольниковым было еще несколько предложений в цитате, я не стала печатать, суть не в этом. Меня интересует именно сам способ оформления цитаты. Ни в одном из приведенных мною примеров (и можно найти немало других в реальных монографиях, статьях) нет глаголов речи, чувств, мимики, нет существительных со значением речи. Однако оформление цитаты как при прямой речи. Я в курсе, что в БСП ставится двоеточие, когда вторая часть поясняет содержание первой, но, когда цитата встраивается как органическая часть предложения, она пишется со строчной, а тут она везде с прописной.

Comment: Прописные на строчные в цитатах нельзя менять, то есть пишем так, как в оригинале. *когда цитата встраивается как органическая часть предложения* — в этих примерах нет такого, потому что тогда она является частью простого предложения, а не сложного. Пояснение и раскрытие содержания (когда рассказываем о чём-то) — это не одно и то же. Получается, что делаем обычное (то, что указано в правилах), но цитатой. Только вот цитата в подтверждение после двоеточия стандартом не является, потому что в правилах такого нет. Но думаю, что допустимо.